# How to make a init script instead of a service file

Tags: centos, init-script, sysvinit

I'm installing rocket.chat on CentOS6, following [this tutorial](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/centos/). It gives the first half of the instructions in CentOS7 and 6, but then when it comes to making it run as a service, it omits 6's instructions.

For CentOS7, it suggests making making a service file but since 6 uses init scripts and I don't know how to write init scripts, I'm like a kid in a labratory.

The service file has the following in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Rocket.Chat server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target nginx.target mongod.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /opt/Rocket.Chat/main.js
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=rocketchat
User=root
Environment=MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/rocketchat ROOT_URL=http://your-host-name.com-as-accessed-from-internet:3000/ PORT=3000
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've made a file `/etc/init.d/rocketchat` and made it executable. I pasted the above in but it obviously isn't liking a lot of that syntax when I run it.

How would this init script be different to a service?

Answer (score -2):

It's a systemd service file. Place to `/lib/systemd/system/`
Or if you have no systemd, then use the initscript from the previous version of Rocket.Chat.

Comment: CentOS 6 doesn't used systemd. The question is asking how to create a shell script for SysV init based on the quoted systemd service file.

Comment: Then he can use the initscript from the previous version.

Comment: I don't think rocket.chat has been around long enough that there is a script around for it. Maybe I'm just bad at searching.